# Align large text and small text horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align small text to the bottom of large text.My code is given below.

I am getting:

[image]

I want to achieve this image output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vF8p.png]

```
<div style="width: 60%;float: left;height: 100%;    display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;flex-direction: column;text-align: left;margin-top: 25px;">
  <span class="Tacivity_head">Total Activity</span>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <span class="Tacivity_head">12100</span>
    <span >10% Last Week</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just change the font size to x-small

Answer (score 1):

try flex `align-items: flex-end;`, check this for more about [flex](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

```css
.Tacivity_head{
font-size:35px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.nunber-container{
display:flex;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 60%;float: left;height: 100%;    display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;flex-direction: column;text-align: left;margin-top: 25px;">
    <span class="Tacivity_head">Total Activity</span>
    <div style="nunber-container">
        <span class="Tacivity_head">12100</span>
        <span >10% Last Week</span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to make you text appear smaller:

With `font-size: 10px;  // enter your px there` 
Or with `font-size: x-small;`

Margin will be necessary in this approach because the small font is moved upwards. 
You can then define your margin in your CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="Test">10% Last Week</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Test{
    // flexible values, adapt these for your case
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day sir, I'll first personally advice you to separate the css from the html either by using the `<style>` at the head tag or an external file using the `<link>` then secondly with regards to the subscript, why don't you use the `<sub>` tag for the spanned "10Last week" try this new one lets see... have a nice day sir

Answer (score 0):

Align items to baseline will be ok?

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.ft__xs {
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="Tacivity_head">Total Activity</span>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: baseline">
    <span class="Tacivity_head">12,100</span>
    <span class="ft__xs">10% Last Week</span>
  </div>
</div>
```